# Single sign on - service for multiple organizations (ADFS and Form Auth mixed)

Tags: c#, single-sign-on

I want to develop an centralized application where different organization users can log-in and perform operations in my site later i will generate report out of it and give it to each organization. I am maintaining my own SQL DB where i will save all the organization issuer , certificate thumbprint details etc….I am able to dynamically send the signinRequest based on the Organization id. However, while coming back from their ADFS server with the token i need following details to be added in my web.config to validate the token. I dont want to expose these details in my web.config for 2 reasons.
- Security [i need to have all the organizations details in config which may result some fraud access]
-Performance [if i have 100 organization who is going to use my app, is it advisible to configure all the issuerauthority in my config. wont it hit the performance]

```
    <issuerNameRegistry type=”System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry”>
   < authority name=”name”>
    <keys>
    <add thumbprint="{Org 1 thumbprint}"/>
    <add thumbprint="{Org 2 thumbprint}"/>
    <add thumbprint="{Org 3 thumbprint}"/>
    </keys>
    <validIssuers>
    <add name="http://test.login.edu/adfs/service/trust&quot;>
    <add name="Org 3 url">
    <add name="Org 4 url">
    <add name="Org 5 url">
    </validIssuers>
    </authority>
    </issuerNameRegistry>
```

Your help will be very much appreciated
Thanks
Jeevitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some research, i have come up with the solution and it works fine too..

I will have the following setting in my web, config. [My custom class with do the return token validation from the issuer]

```
 <issuerNameRegistry type="ADFS_Lib.AccessControlServiceIssuerNameRegistry, ADFS_Lib">
      </issuerNameRegistry>
```

In my class, i will be overridding the IssuerRegistry calss GetIssuerName method and validate the return token and issuer in my DB whether its configured or not

```
 public class AccessControlServiceIssuerNameRegistry : IssuerNameRegistry
    {
 public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken, string requestedIssuerName)
        {
//here my DB validation code goes 
}
```